# java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws, soap-client, mtom

I am developing a web service to allow uploading from client to server. I was able to get wsdl file at `http://localhost:9999/UploadWebservice?wsdl`. Here is its content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6. -->
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6. -->
<definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://ws/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://ws/" name="ImageServerImplService">
    <types></types>
    <message name="upload">
        <part name="arg0" type="xsd:string"></part>
        <part name="arg1" type="xsd:base64Binary"></part>
    </message>
    <message name="uploadResponse">
        <part name="return" type="xsd:string"></part>
    </message>
    <portType name="ImageServer">
        <operation name="upload" parameterOrder="arg0 arg1">
            <input message="tns:upload"></input>
            <output message="tns:uploadResponse"></output>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="ImageServerImplPortBinding" type="tns:ImageServer">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"></soap:binding>
        <operation name="upload">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://ws/"></soap:body>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://ws/"></soap:body>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="ImageServerImplService">
        <port name="ImageServerImplPort" binding="tns:ImageServerImplPortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:9999/UploadWebservice"></soap:address>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Now I am writing a client to consume the service. Here is the client

```
package ws;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding;

import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties;

public class ClientTaiwan {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageServerImplService service = new ImageServerImplService();
        ImageServer delegate = service.getImageServerImplPort();

        // Enable MTOM
        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) delegate;
        SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding) bp.getBinding();
        binding.setMTOMEnabled(true);

        // Set chunk size           
        Map<String, Object> ctxt =
                ((BindingProvider)delegate).getRequestContext();
                ctxt.put(JAXWSProperties.HTTP_CLIENT_STREAMING_CHUNK_SIZE, 8192);    

        byte[] b;
        try {
            RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("c:\\100MB.zip", "r");
            b = new byte[(int) f.length()];
            f.read(b);
            f.close();
            delegate.upload("c://Upload//100MB.zip", b);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

I receive the following stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:225)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1063)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:979)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:950)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:825)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:443)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.upload(Unknown Source)
    at ws.ClientTaiwan.main(ClientTaiwan.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport$WSChunkedOuputStream.write(HttpClientTransport.java:365)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MtomCodec$ByteArrayBuffer.write(MtomCodec.java:229)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MtomCodec.encode(MtomCodec.java:185)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:214)
```

The line that causes the problem is `delegate.upload("c://Upload//100MB.zip", b);`

Why does a published service is still not visible for its client? How can I fix it?
If you have any concern about my coding style please let me know. Things are a little out of my control right now.

Best regards